# Function invoked inside its body in for loop takes last value instead of sequence value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects:

```
this.array = [{name: null}, {name: null}, {name: null}]
```

and array of reservend names:

```
this.reserved = ["name2", "name3"]
```

I loop through array and try to set uniques name (not included inside `reserved` array)

```
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    this.setDefaultName(array[i], 1);
  }

  private setDefaultName(obj, index){
    if (!this.reserved.includes(`name${index}`)) {
      obj.name = `name${index}`;
      this.reserved.push(`name${index}`);
    } else {
      return this.setDefaultName(obj, index + 1);
    }
  }
```

After that all objects from array have name "name3". The expected result is to have sequence unique name: "name1", "name4", "name5".
Could anyone help me?

Comment: How about calling the `setDefaultName` with `setDefaultName(array[i], i + 1)`?

Comment: I just ran your code, and you are wrong, the array ends up with name's `name1`, `name4` and `name5` as expected

Comment: I did have to fix the fact that you don't use `this.array.length` and `this.array[i]` but that would prevent the code from running at all ... perhaps the code here is not representative of the real code you have an issue with

Comment: P.S. I don't like the unnecessary recursion of `setDefaultName` - even `function setDefaultName(obj, index) { while(this.reserved.includes(\`name${index}\`)) ++index; this.reserved.push(obj.name = \`name${index}\`); }` is better than recursion

Answer (score 0):

I adjust some of your code to make it runnable on snippet. It looks like it works though. Can you recheck?

```js
let nameArray = [{name: null}, {name: null}, {name: null}]
let reserved = ["name2", "name3"]

for (let i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
  setDefaultName(nameArray[i], 1);
}

function setDefaultName(obj, index){
  if (!reserved.includes(`name${index}`)) {
    obj.name = `name${index}`;
    reserved.push(`name${index}`);
  } else {
    return this.setDefaultName(obj, index + 1);
  }
}

console.log(nameArray)
```

Comment: its angular that's why there is no function keyword - i was confused as well and the code actually seems to be working in plain JS

Answer (score 0):

I created a StackBliz demo which is as close as possible to your code and it is actually working fine!
You may compare this demo with yours:
[StackBliz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8vnrsb?file=index.js)